# CakePHP: help me with error validate ( why error is miss field when data have that field )

Tags: cakephp, validation

Gallery model

```
var $validate = array(
          'id' => array('rule' => 'numeric', 'required' => true, 'allowEmpty' => false, 'on' => 'update'),
          'name' => array('rule' => 'notEmpty', 'required' => true, 'allowEmpty' => false, 'on' => 'create'),
          'model' => array('rule' => 'notEmpty', 'required' => true, 'allowEmpty' => false, 'on' => 'create'),
          'model_id' => array('rule' => 'numeric', 'required' => true, 'allowEmpty' => false, 'on' => 'create'),
          'status' => array('rule' => array('inList', array('Draft', 'Publish')), 'message' => 'FAILED', 'allowEmpty' => false)
      );
```

action  controller

```
  private function admin_edit() {
        if (!empty($this->data['Gallery']['id'])) {
              debug($this->data);
              if ($this->Gallery->save($this->data)) {

              }
              debug($this->Gallery->invalidFields());

        }
        $this->redirect('/');
  }
```

This is error , please help me

```
app\controllers\galleries_controller.php (line 149)
Array
(
    [Gallery] => Array
        (
            [id] => 38
            [name] => Chap 6
            [status] => Publish
        )

)

app\controllers\galleries_controller.php (line 153)
Array
(
    [id] => This field cannot be left blank
)
```

why it error miss id when data have id field, MODEL dont use behavior, only ContainableBehavior

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have validation on your id field... cake handles all that for you automatically...

If the id isn't set then it creates new entry, if it's set it will update.